# If Wi-Fi connection drops internet, can device failover to network connection?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, data-connection

Once in awhile the internet will drop on the network that my phone is connected to via Wi-Fi. It's pretty rare, but in instances when it happens, my phone remains connected to the network but won't receive notifications. I won't know that it's not connected unless I'm intentionally attempting to do something that requires internet access at which point I can just disable Wi-Fi.

I imagine that my phone should be able to figure out it no longer has internet access even if it's connected to a network. Is there a way to have it failover to the provider's 4G/LTE connection when this happens?

My device is a Galaxy S6 Edge+ running Android 5.1.1

Comment: That's odd... Every Android phone I have ever had (Nexus 4, Nexus 5, LG G2, HTC One M7, and others) including my current Moto G 2015 do this automatically, in fact it happens occasionally at a hotel I stay at frequently. It does take a few minutes sometimes, but I will pull the phone out of my pocket and the WiFi indicator is still there but with an Exclamation Mark on it, and the LTE is connected again... when the WiFi fixes it self then after a little while it stops using mobile data. Although I don't see an option in mine, check your WiFi settings Advanced area and see if there is an option

Answer (score 1):

In the Wi-Fi settings, there's a feature called "Smart Network Switch" which is described as:

> If Smart network swich is on, your device will be connected to a mobile network automatically when the Wi-Fi connection is unstable.

So I had this off, which I assume is by default on my phone. Turning it on I assume resolves the issue.